# How to accept PRs in a Git Flow environment?

Tags: github, pull-request, git-flow

I've got my first repo that people are interested in contributing to, but I'm totally lost on how to set up the repo so that it respects the Git Flow methodology I've been using while coding by myself.

What do I need to set up? Should I set the default branch to develop instead of master? Do I just need to instruct contributors that they need to use Git Flow and please create their feature under `feature/`, and submit PRs that way?

Answer (score 1):

Okay the following are my personal thoughts and others might have different ideas :)

I always set the default branch to develop.

I manually do the PR's from github.
I select `command line instructions` in the PR and download the patch.
I create a feature branch myself, apply the downloaded patch, check the work and fix things if needed (code styling for example), and finish the feature.

Like I said, others might have different ideas about it, but this works for me.